# What is the difference between the two arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I understand 'this' in the arrow function points to this in the upper excution context.

```js
var name = 'aaa';
const person = {
    name: 'bbb',
    getName: () => {return console.log(this.name)}
}
person.getName();
```

so I understand that getName() is logging the name of the global object in the code above.

```js
const name = 'aaa';
const Person = function() {
    this.name = 'bbb';
    this.getName = () => {return console.log(this.name)}
}
const test = new Person();
test.getName();
```

However, the test object in this code is an object that is created as a Person constructor. Therefore, I think getName() of test object is the same as this used in method in object as above code. What did I understand wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in arrow functions is defined by the enclosing lexical context. A regular object doesn't define a `this` local to the object. So the lookup continues outward and you get the global object. On the other hand when you use the `new` operator with a function it creates an object and explicitly sets `this` to point to that object. That is the value of `this` the arrow function will see because that is the value of `this` in the immediate lexical context.

It's confusing because a regular function uses different rules to define `this`. For example, this works with a plain object:

```js
const person = {
    name: 'bbb',
    // non-arrow function
    getName() { console.log(this.name)}
}
person.getName();
```

You can see the way an arrow function will define `this` by looking outward to enclosing contexts by combing your examples:

```js
const Person = function() {
    this.fname = 'Bob';
    this.obj = {
      getName: () => { console.log(this.fname)}
    }
   
}
const test = new Person();
test.obj.getName();
```

Comment: If I understand you @김종현, then yes, the object created by the constructor is just and object. The arrow function created by the object literal is a function.

Answer (score 2):

```
const person = {
    name: 'bbb',
    getName: () => {return console.log(this.name)}
}
```

By this way, you have defined an object name `person` with 2 properties `name` and `getName`. The type of `name` is a string while the type of `getName` is a function (*arrow function*). One of the differences between a normal function and an arrow function is the way to use `this` keyword.

Since `person` is an object and NOT a function, you cannot create new instanceof this object:

```
var p = new person(); // Error: person is not a constructor
```

Otherwise, if `Person` is a function

```
const Person = function() {
    this.name = 'bbb';
    this.getName = () => {return console.log(this.name)}
}
```

then, you could create new instance of it:

```
const test = new Person();
```

This function has 2 properties, too. The type of both properties are same to the first's.

---

For your question, I suggest you to check `this` object inside the functions:

```js
const person = {
    name: 'bbb',
    getName: () => {console.log(this)}
}

person.getName();
```

```js
const Person = function() {
    this.name = 'bbb';
    this.getName = () => {console.log(this)}
}
const test = new Person();
test.getName();
```